# i want to change the fifth column

Tags: html

Idk what to do, I'm new and my teacher doesn't give me permission to write CSS file

here is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bảng kết quả học tập</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 align="center">DANH SÁCH HỌC PHẦN</h2>
  <table align="center" border="2" width="800px">
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="3">Nhóm học phần</th>
      <th rowspan="3">Học phần</th>
      <th colspan="2">Số tín chỉ</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Lý thuyết</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Thực hành<br>BTL</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="5">I<br>Cơ sở ngành</th>
      <th rowspan="4">II<br>Chuyên ngành</th>

    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Change the 5th column to do what?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Your post does not include any question. What do you intend this code to do? Maybe attach a picture how you want it to look in a browser. If you need to add styles you can go with (1) a separate CSS file, (2) add styles to the `style` tag in `head` of the html document or (3) attach style parameters to any tag in the html body.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you wish to change but the below code will align your table. Column 5 and column 6 are now aligned with the rest of the columns. Rather than making a new `<tr></tr>` for columns 5 and 6 just add them in the first row itself.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bảng kết quả học tập</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h2 align="center">DANH SÁCH HỌC PHẦN</h2>
  <table align="center" border="2" width="800px">
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Nhóm học phần</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Học phần</th>
      <th colspan="2">Số tín chỉ</th>
      <th rowspan="2">I<br>Cơ sở ngành</th>
      <th rowspan="2">II<br>Chuyên ngành</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Lý thuyết</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Thực hành<br>BTL</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```